# Two map methods inside map method

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my example, I have an array of objects which I want to map to another array of objects:

```
Resurs.map((item) => ({
  Cen: item.Cent,
  level: [
    item.NumList.map((item) => ({
      Kom: item.Number,
      Num: item.Kor,
    })),
    item.SerList.map((item) => ({
      Kom2: item.Ser,
    })),
  ],
}));
```

So, I have 2 map methods inside the map method. It will return:

```
{
  Cen: "aaa",
  level: [
    [ // -> want to get rid of this
      {
        Kom: "aaa",
        Num: "aaa",
      },
      {
        Kom: "bbb",
        Num: "bbb",
      },
    ], // -> and this
    [ //-> and this
      { Kom2: "aaa" },
      { Kom2: "bbb" },
    ], //-> and this
  ],
};
```

So, both map functions need to be inside `level` key, but not as a list which has two lists inside, but as a list with objects.

So, I want to achieve:

```
{
  Cen: "aaa",
  level: [
    {
      Kom: "aaa",
      Num: "aaa",
    },
    {
      Kom: "bbb",
      Num: "bbb",
    },
    { Kom2: "aaa" },
    { Kom2: "bbb" },
  ],
};
```

Comment: You want `Array.prototype.flat`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Comment: You can use a spread operator

Comment: if `level` is your array, then `level.flat()` is what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there! The answer is spread operator. Just insert it in your inner map.

You can use a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to expanded the arrays when you insert into level.

The spread operator can be used with an array or an object.

Example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = [5, 6, 7];

var c = [a, b];   //  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]  // This is what you are doing

Solution: 
var d = [...a, ...b];   //  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

**Complete Solution:**

```js
const Resurs = [
    {
        Cent:  "centValue",
        NumList: [
            {
                Number: "numValue1",
                Kor: "KorValue1"
            },
            {
                Number: "numValue3",
                Kor: "KorValue2"
            },
            {
                Number: "numValue3",
                Kor: "KorValue3"
            }
        ],
        SerList: [
            {
                Ser: "SerValue1"
            },
            {
                Ser: "SerValue2"
            }
        ]
    }
];
const data = Resurs.map((item) => ({
  Cen: item.Cent,
  level: [
    ...item.NumList.map((item) => ({   // Just add ...
      Kom: item.Number,
      Num: item.Kor,
    })),
    ...item.SerList.map((item) => ({   // Just add ...
      Kom2: item.Ser,
    })),
  ],
}));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the outer array in the first place:

```
const data = Resurs.map((item) => ({
  Cen: item.Cent,
  level: item.NumList.map((item) => ({
      Kom: item.Number,
      Num: item.Kor,
    })).concat(item.SerList.map((item) => ({
      Kom2: item.Ser,
    }))),
}));
```